# SQLite database query exception handling

Tags: c#, database, exception

I am retrieving some data drom a SQLite database table & am using the following code :-

```
try
{
  for (double i = 10; i < 100; i++)
  {
    // Read in value
    cmd.CommandText = "SELECT Value FROM Data WHERE Value like '" + i + "'";
    Digit_Value = Convert.ToDouble(cmd.ExecuteScalar());
  }
catch (Exception)
{
  throw;
}
```

All works as required until it hits a `Null` in the database table, and then an exception is thrown.

I need to assign the value of 0.00 to the variable Digit_Value when the exception is thrown & the routine should continue onto the next record. Numerous google searches has uncovered nothing that works - any pointers ?

Comment: Where is exception thrown and which exception?

Comment: As a coding tip, you'll want to try and avoid building SQL queries like that. Please have a Google around parameterized queries.

Comment: If all you're doing is `catch (Exception) { throw; }`, don't bother with the try-catch at all.

Comment: The exception is thrown on the line Digit_Value = Convert.ToDouble(cmd.ExecuteScalar()); 
I am assuming it has an issue converting a NULL value to double as the exception reads - Object cannot be cast from DBNull to other types.

Comment: Unfortunately parameters with SQLite are proving a nightmare :(   If I remove the try-catch then the code runs but as soon as it hits the null then it exits the loop.

Comment: Effectively I need it to hit the null, catch the exception & assign a value of 0 to the variable & then continue on to the next item in the database. I cant figure out howto do this though.

Comment: RE:  _If I remove the try-catch then the code runs but as soon as it hits the null then it exits the loop._ -- how does the code provided not do that as well?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the ExecuteScalar() method is returning Null (or DbNull?) then you need to detect that before trying to assign it to Digit_Value:

```
cmd.CommandText = "SELECT Value FROM Data WHERE Value like '" + i + "'";
object o = cmd.ExecuteScalar();
if(o == Null) {
  throw new Exception("Got null");
} else {
  Digit_Value = Convert.ToDouble(o);
}
```

Comment: @RoadBump It can return `DBNull.Value` also, if selected value is `NULL`.

Answer (score 0):

`ExecuteScalar` returns the first cell of the first row in the query ([MSDN Reference](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.executescalar.aspx)).

Given this, just modify your query to this:

```
SELECT Value FROM Data WHERE Value like '@value' UNION select 0
```

Answer (score 0):

If you don't use wildcard character with LIKE then use `=` instead.

```
try
{
  cmd.Parameters.Add("@val", SqlDbType.Int32);
  cmd.CommandText = "SELECT Value FROM Data WHERE Value = @val";

  for (double i = 10; i < 100; i++)
  {
    // Read in value
    cmd.Parameters["@val"].Value = i;
    object res = cmd.ExecuteScalar();
    double? Digit_Value = DBNull.Value.Equals(res) ? null : Convert.ToDouble(res);
  }
catch (Exception)
{
  throw;
}
```